# Mi consulta preparada no inserta información en mi base de datos ¿Se debe a un error mío o del servidor?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Mi problemas es el siguiente hice una aplicación web de ordenes y consultas con usuarios. Al momento de querer insertar una orden no se me registra en la base de datos, la aplicación funciona en modo local (XAMPP) pero ya estando en el servidor no me deja registrar ordenes.

Ya revise el código y según yo esta bien. Tengo los permisos en mi usuario de la base de datos y el php actualizado en el servidor. Si me muestra información de la base de datos pero a la hora de insertar no me deja hacerlo. Es curioso porque en el servidor no me devuelve un error, o no se si estoy manejando lo errores de forma correcta.

Dejo un fragmento de código de mi consulta en php:

```
//Insertado sql de computadora
                $sqlInsertComp = "INSERT INTO computadorascat(cr, 
                                                              tienda, 
                                                              fecha, 
                                                              folio,
                                                              subcat,
                                                              estatus, 
                                                              solucion, 
                                                              mes, 
                                                              usuario,
                                                              categoria) 
                                                              VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                $resultado = $con->prepare($sqlInsertComp);
                $resultado->bind_param(
                    'sssissssss',
                    $_POST['cr-input-nuevaOrden'],
                    $_POST['tienda-span-modal-mto'],
                    $_POST['date-nuevaOrden'], 
                    $_POST['folio-nueva-orden'],
                    $subcategoria,
                    $_POST['status-new-orden'],
                    $descripcion,
                    $mesActual,
                    $_SESSION["userName"],
                    $_POST["select-cat-nueva-orden"]

                   
                );
    
                $resultado->execute();
                
                if($resultado == false){
                    print_r($con->error);
                }
                print_r(1);
```

**servidor:** Neubox con Cpanel

**Version de php:** 7.4

Comment: otras querys te funcionan bien? como un select y listar los datos (?)

Comment: Cuento 10 interrogantes en la pregunta y 11 parámetros en el `bind_param`, estás seguro de que está bien?

Comment: Si, los select y updates funcionan bien y son 10 interrogantes y 10 parametros en el bind_param. Funciona bien en local pero en el serividor no se ejecutan los insert

Comment: Y estas mirando la misma base de datos en todos los casos? he visto de gente que decia que no le agregaba cosas, y en su servidor tenia mas de una base de datos...

Comment: Tengo mas de una base de datos, pero si, el script de conexión apunta a la base de datos correcta, de hecho me muestra información de la base de datos, lo que no hace son las inserciones con la consulta preparada.